# Conversion from CPP to Java (dp =1)

Tags: java, c++, arrays, pointers

I have code to be converted from CPP to Java. I have been though almost all but few confusing things as never worked on CPP.

I wanted to understand following CPP code and How can I represent it in Java:

```
UInt8* data;
memcpy(data, rawData, rawDataLen);
UInt8* dp = data;
dp += 8; //Is it updating the Array Index?
char buf[256];
sizeof(buf) //Can I take it as Length?
```

Please suggest.

Comment: First step would be realizing that this is not C++ but C code.

Comment: ok may be I considered C++ because of file extension.

Comment: There are many weird people out there, who write C code in a file with `.cpp` extension, compile it as C++ and if the compilation is successful, they claim themselves to be C++ programmers.

Comment: @LihO Just because you use code that can basically be compiled in C doesn't make the question about C. If you're compiling a C++ program, it's C++. Admittedly this question is probably better marked C, since it doesn't actually have much to do with compiling the code as is.

Comment: @Dukeling: For me it is just a C++-compilable C.

Comment: This code is nonsense. Porting it to Java would be a waste of time.

Comment: @PeteBecker When it's client suggestion it has to be done. And there is nothing non-sense in it my friend. Rather invest time in implementation. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @JavaAster - that call to `memcpy` writes to random memory. `sizeof(buf)` is a valid expression, but it has no effect at the point where it's written.

Answer (score 2):

To your first question:

```
dp += 8;
```

yes this sets the pointer of the position in your array up. So in java it would mean, that you update your array index.

To the second:

```
sizeof(buf);
```

sizeof returns the number of bytes, not the number of elements. So in your case it really is the length, BUT only, because `sizeof(char) = 1`. This is depending on the system. For example `sizeof(short) = 2` on most systems. So if your `buf` were a short array the `sizeof(buf)` would be equal to two times the length, in most cases.

Comment: And also `System.arraycopy()` to copy array data.

Comment: `sizeof` isn't really the number of bytes. The standard states that `sizeof(char) == 1` must hold. So your statement is true on most systems (where char is a byte), but it is implementation defined.

Comment: @StoryTeller - "byte" in the C++ language definition is equivalent to `char`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, the C and C++ languages may interchange `char` for "byte", but since the size of such a "byte" is not always 8 bits I think it's better to just talk in `char`s and not in bytes.

Comment: @StoryTeller - it's not that simple. What does "byte" mean on a system where the basic unit of addressable storage holds 9 bits? On all systems, `sizeof(T)` gives the number of bytes that an object of type `T` occupies. It really isn't appropriate to say that it occupies some number of `char`s, because `char` is a type and has properties that don't necessarily apply to a different type. If you reject "byte" then you need the circumlocution that `sizeof(T)` returns a number that designates the number of objects in an array of `char` that would occupy the same space as an object of type `T`.